# Ajax error struts2?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I have in my action class:

```
try{

        tspNameIdMap = slsReqMgmtCommonRemote.getTspNameIdMap(Integer.parseInt(circleId));

        throw new ReqMgmtException("Message test");
    }
    catch(ReqMgmtException rEx){

        addActionError("Action-Error: Request Management Exception thrown");
        return ERROR;
        }
```

I am doing an AJAX call and using **Struts2-Json-plugin** to get `tspNameIdMap` in JSON form.

**JS: Part of AJAX:**

```
success: function(data){
                alert('Updated DB');
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
```

**My `struts.xml`:**

```
<action name="findTspNameIdMap"
            class="cdot.oss.cmsat.gma.struts.ConfigureTspThresholdAction" method="findTspNameIdMap">
            <result name="success" type="json">
                <param name="root">
                    tspNameIdMap                    <!-- tspNameIdMap will be returned in JSON form -->
                </param>
            </result>
        </action>
```

I want my `addActionError` message in my Ajax error function. I will also want to display it in my JSP then. How can I get this?

Ps: Do I have to include this ActionError message in a properties file? I am using it for first time. Help

**EDIT** : As i followed @Prabhakar answer I got the error message, but it got returned in the `success` of the AJAX call.

Another issue is that, when i put this in my JSP, the `actionerror` is not getting displayed.

**Jsp:**

```
<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
       <s:actionerror />
</s:if>
```

Comment: you want to show the action errors in the same jsp??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure result `ERROR` to return the rendered error page fragment to the Ajax response.

```
<result name="error">/error.jspx</result>
```

**error.jspx:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%
    request.setAttribute("decorator", "none");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
    response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server
%>
<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
       <s:actionerror />
</s:if>
```

Comment: I don't need to use <param name="includeProperties">
        actionErrors.*
    </param> ??????

Comment: The result is of type `dispatcher`, so no properties.

Comment: I did what u said. However, the error jsp is not being displayed. It remains on the same jsp and the error jsp is returned as the result of AJAX call. Thus my dropdown gets filled with html of error jsp where JSON data had to come through AJAX

Comment: You can fill the html to any div on the page with jQuery selector and `html()` function.

Comment: So then my 1st jsp will have an error div where i my error.jsp will be loaded. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, better to use div with `id` attribute and use it in selector to populate div.

Comment: Whether in struts.xml it's error or success returned, data is returnrd to success function of AJAX call. So how should I differntiate whether JSON data I want is coming or the error paga???

Comment: `if(typeof data !== 'object') {//this is HTML`

Comment: If i send 2-3 parameters to be sent using json plugin then typeof data will be Object[] object i guess. Then this will fail?

Comment: You should try it and tell me if it worked or not, because I didn't use it.

Comment: I tried returning more than parameter using json plugin, it stll returns it as object. Thus typeof data is 'object'. I guess it's because it returns a JSON object. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Please check the following

In your **struts.xml** edit the following

```
<result name="success" type="json">
  <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
    <param name="includeProperties">
        actionErrors.*,
        actionMessages.*,
        fieldErrors.*
    </param>
</result>
```

And in your **js code** edit the below.

```
    var actionErrs= (data.actionErrors); // list of action errors
    var actionMsgs= (data.actionMessages); // list of action messages
    var actionFldErrs= (data.fieldErrors); // list of field errors

   var alertMessage="";
    var i=0;
    for(i=0;i<actionErrs.length; i++){
    alertMessage=alertMessage+" "+actionMessages[i];
    }

    alert(alertMessage);
```

**Edit**
in your **JSP** instead of the following,

```
<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
       <s:actionerror />
</s:if>
```

use

```
<div id="err"></div>
```

and add below line in you **js code**

```
document.getElementById("err").innerHTML=alertMessage;
```

to check the **result name**

if your method signature like below,

```
public String getJsonData(){
if(....){
return ERROR;
}
return SUCCESS
}
```

You can get the data in your js code as below,

```
var actionErrs= (data.actionErrors); // list of action errors
var actionMsgs= (data.actionMessages); // list of action messages
var actionFldErrs= (data.fieldErrors); // list of field errors

var resultName=(data.getJsonData); // get The method return value

var alertMessage="";
var i=0;
for(i=0;i<actionErrs.length; i++){
alertMessage=alertMessage+" "+actionMessages[i];
}

alert(alertMessage);
```

Comment: @Prabhaskar : what if I want to use actionError??

Comment: On success, I want to return tspNameIdMap and when return error I want actionErrors

Comment: Whether in struts.xml it's error or success returned, data is returnrd to success function of AJAX call. So how should I differntiate whether JSON data I want is coming or the error paga???

Comment: you can check the  result name success or error with json data in the same page with out any other error result. check my ans.

Comment: I din understand your last edit. How are u calling action class function i.e getJsonData from js code? Come again?

Comment: Yes, the same way how you are getting the actions errors from the json data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43988/discussion-between-prabhakar-manthena-and-siddharth-trikha)