# show error message on struts2 jquery dialog box

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, struts2

i have made a simple wepp app in struts2 that logs in and add user the log in and registration page are all running ok..but i had a problem when i registered the same email it was successful i wanted to add a simple error that when the email is already registered it may not be used again to register another user i found a couple of validation but it does not answer my question ideas on how to do this kind of validation is appreciated

this is a similar problem but it has no answer as well http://www.rqna.net/qna/ypywn-how-to-show-error-message-on-struts2-jquery-dialog-box.html

i read this one but i think its a different kind of validation http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/fielderror.html

Comment: Hi please chek the following link it may help.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795421/ajax-error-struts2/20796174#20796174][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795421/ajax-error-struts2/20796174#20796174

Comment: See also [ActionError not getting displayed?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20857030/573032).

Comment: those are great sources but are there any way to show just a message on top or below that says "your email is already in use" something like this and doesnt need to use js or load another page?its a simple webb app as that.any ideas are appreciated thank you roman and prabhakar

Answer (score 0):

found a very simple solution to this i just put

```
addFieldError("email","user email already in use");
```

and it worked the way i wanted it to work